# react-leaflet : find data displayed on map when zoom level changes

Tags: reactjs, maps, react-leaflet

I have a list of locations displayed alongside leaflet map. The map displays all the locations on the list. When I zoom in the map, the visible locations on the map decrease (as expected). Now, I would like to filter the list to display only those locations which are visible on the map. Can someone help me achieve this? I am using react-leaflet and openstreet maps.

Yes, please see the code below.

```
<Map center={mapCenter}
 zoom={5} maxZoom={OpportunityMap.LEAFLET_MAX_ZOOM} minZoom={2} zoomControl={true} ref={el => this.map = el} onZoomEnd={this.handleZoomStart(this.map)} >
handleZoomStart(map) {
        if(map) {
            let bounds = map.leafletElement.getBounds();
            map.leafletElement.eachLayer(function(layer){
                if(bounds.contains(layer.getBounds()))
                //here 
 }); 
 } 
}
```

I get below error

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined'

because lat and long is not defined for 'layer.getBounds()'.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please share the code so that we can help you.

Comment: @Think-Twice added code snippet in the quesn above. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

There might be another way to do this, however I would go like this;

After any zoom action, I would run the function `map.getBounds();` (you can do this in the ComponentDidUpdate() function) and check if the listed location is staying inside this bound or not. Then, I can easily update my location list.

Comment: I have tried this approach and added the code in the question along with the error. Please have a look.

Comment: You should know the lat-lng info of the location list you have. Then you should compare bounds with them.